# Specifying a random monitoring port with autossh

Tags: ssh-tunneling, openssh, port-forwarding

I have many reverse ssh tunnels and because monitoring ports can't be reused, I am trying to find a free random port for monitoring.

Meanwhile I specified -M 0 and the forwards work great and in most cases: when there is a disconnection, it will automatically reconnect. However, sometimes, on rare occasion, a connection will hang and think it is connected even if it has gone stale.

Is it possible to setup a random monitoring port?

What I tried:

1. When I specify a port with -M [port] , I can't monitor more than one connect
2. When I specify -M 0 and use ServerAlive, rarely the connection hangs
3. I added ClientAlive in sshd_config and specify ServerAlive in the command line

Because my reverse port forward occasionally becomes stale, it makes it unreliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer:

1. have an echo server on the ssh server and specify that as the monitoring port for all connections (better but requires setting up an echo server)
2. find an available port range and have a way for each connection to create a unique port forward on a different port.

Comment: what is a echo server? Can you expand your answer with some examples?

Comment: Sorry haven't used stack exchange for a while. An echo server is one of the standard server daemons that takes the text sent by the client and spits it back out. The monitor option sends text at a regular interval and expects it back, if it doesn't get it back it means it's not connected and reconnects. I ended up writing a script that tried to make an sql connection and if it failed after a specified amount of tries it forced a reconnect. I hope this helps